# Определение местоположение пользователя

Tags: ip

Здравствуйте,

Пробовали определять по IP, но выходит очень неточно (путаються города).
Пробовали через W3C Geolocation API (но там браузер требует подтверджение, чтоб отпугивает пользователей).

Можна определять местоположениче пользователя(город) как, например у foursquare.com ?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете тут попробовать: [GeoIP Databases and Services](http://www.maxmind.com/en/home) 
По IP вообще со 100% точностью город не определить.

4sq использует MapBox на основе OpenStreetMaps